# do.call based on output of previous sapply(seq_along()) iteration

Tags: r, sapply, do.call

I have a named list of some algorithm, which may look like this

```
> algorithm
$rBinarize
$rBinarize$x
[1] 40
```

and may contain an arbitrary number of additional algorithms. Each algorithm carries out an operation on a spatial object (`spObj`, of class raster) and returns the modified raster. I would then like to use `do.call` to (s)apply this (and all the other) algorithm(s) within a parent function to the original input. However, what I additionally want to achieve is a sequential application of the defined algorithms, i.e. on the output of the previous algorithm. I came up with the following code, but I am curious about additional suggestions to improve the performance, given it is possible.

```
if(sequential){
  for(k in seq_along(algorithm)){
    if(length(algorithm[[k]])==0){
      args <- c(spObj = spObj)
    } else{
      args <- c(algorithm[[k]], spObj = spObj)
    }
    spObj <- do.call(what = names(algorithm)[k], args = args)
  }
} else{
  algorithm2 <- lapply(algorithm, function(x) x <- c(x, spObj = spObj))
  modified <- sapply(seq_along(algorithm2), function(j) do.call(what = names(algorithm2)[[j]], args = algorithm2[[j]]))
}
```

Wouldn't it possible to use some sort of `apply()` construction instead of the `for`-loop? I am not sure if I simply don't understand the logic of `apply`/`do.call` sufficiently or if this is actually not possible in R.

---

I modified to for-loop to make it comparable with Davids suggestion and ran a microbenchmark on it:

```
microbenchmark(a = for(k in seq_along(alg)){
  if(length(alg[[k]][-1])==0){
    args <- c(spObj = spObj)
  } else{
    args <- c(alg[[k]][-1], spObj = spObj)
  }
  spObj <- do.call(what = alg[[k]]$algorithm, args = args)
},
b = Reduce(f = function(x, y) do.call(what = y$algorithm, args = c(list(x), y[-1])),
       x = alg,
       init = spObj))
```

Which resulted in

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
    a 33.36777 35.22067 39.60699 36.79661 40.75072 152.0171   100
    b 33.35236 35.39173 40.32860 37.51993 40.25102 154.0441   100
```

Is this one of these examples where a for-loop is in fact not slower than any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in `Reduce` function.

As a simple example, suppose your chain looked like this:

```
algorithms <- list(list(func = "sin"),
                   list(func = "cos"),
                   list(func = "log", base = 2))
```

You'd like this to apply the equivalent of `log(cos(sin(x)), 2)`. Note that I've changed your input structure to have an item in each list called `func` rather than have that be the names.

You can then apply these with:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) do.call(y$func, c(list(x), y[-1])),
       algorithms,
       init = spObj)
```

For example, if `spObj` starts as `10`, this results in `-0.2249337`, which you'll notice is the same as `log(cos(sin(spObj)), 2)`.

You may need to adapt this slightly to your use case depending on the functions you're using, but `Reduce` is generally what you're looking for.

Comment: awesome, I will try it later, but looks like the solution. Thanks!

Comment: This does, however, not result in better performance of the code.

Comment: @SteffenEhrmann Why would you expect it to? 1. The reason functional patterns can sometimes speed up code involves how they build and modify data structures, but that doesn't apply to this case. 2. The vast majority of your function time is surely spent within the functions at each step (especially if they're spatial algorithms), not in the iteration, so no change here would help

Comment: @SteffenEhrmann Here's a good discussion of [when functionals are useful as an alternative to loops](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html)- the main goal is usually expressiveness rather than efficiency

Comment: Ok, thanks for resolving it. I wasn't aware about these things, got my education in another topic ;).